# alternative to function within function in php

Tags: php, function, codeigniter

So I have a function that I call/return to/from ajax. As you can see, there are multiple places where I return data and stop the script if conditionals are met. This is (obviously) far less concise than if I had a function which I passed the error message into and it returned/encoded the json, while stopping the main function from continuing. The problem is I do not know how to BEST structure this sort of thing in PHP, given that functions within functions aren't used.

Sorry for the long code piece... I am not sure how else to properly describe the issue.

Sincere thanks for any help (or other unrelated tips even). It is greatly appreciated.

```
public function mask_as_user() {
    $this->load->model('User_model', '', true);

    $email = $this->input->post('email');

    //there should be some front-end validation here too, but if not permitter, dont allow this to proceed.
    if (strpos($this->session->userdata('user_type'), 'permitter') === false) {
        $return['status'] = 'error';
        $return['message']= 'You are not an admin.';
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($return);
        return false;
    }

    //save the current admin account, so we know where to switch back to
    $admin_account_email = $this->session->userdata('user_email');

    //logout current user to not have overlapping session data
    //$this->logout(false, true);

    $user_data = $this->User_model->get_user_data($email);

    if ($user_data[0]){
        $user_data = $this->clean_user_data($user_data[0]);
    }
    else{
        $return['status'] = 'error';
        $return['message']= 'This is not an active client account.';
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($return);
        return false;
    }
    //get userdata for user-mask account and remove unneccessary data (such as login credentials) from session array

    //prevent switching into admin accounts. Not really any sensitive data that the rest of the company can't access elsewhere, but maybe someday there will be. 
    if (strpos($user_data['user_type'], 'permitter') !== false) {
        $return['status'] = 'error';
        $return['message']= 'You cannot switch into an admin account.';
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($return);
        return false;
    }

    //foreach column loaded from database, create a session value. 
    $this->session->set_userdata($user_data);

    //set user to loggedin.
    $this->session->set_userdata('loggedin', TRUE);

    //set the current admin account which the mask is being applied to. We will need this for returning back to the admin account without having to logout.
    $this->session->set_userdata('admin_account_email', $admin_account_email);

    $return['status'] = 'success';
    $return['redir_url'] = '/site_client/dashboard';

    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($return);

}
```

Comment: It's a little hard to understand what you are trying to ask, or at least I don't understand. Are you just asking "what is the best way to structure this code?", because if so you are likely to just get a generic (and correct) answer like "the best way to structure the code is so you understand it and it works". Nothing here looks so crazy or out of the ordinary that I can see.

Comment: I agreed with @JonathanKuhn that you are looking for is clean code which is basically removed duplicated code and make it shorter. There are multiple ways of doing that. the first I could see from your code is to take out header and echo and put it together like this `function echoReturn($return) { header('Content-type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($return);}`

Comment: yeah, I guess thats what I am asking, but I'm pretty confident its not the best way... I am an amateur but I'm pretty sure the best way is not to repeat the same 4 lines of code four times. I thought there had to be something better. Or maybe it is?

Comment: thanks @thanyaj, I think thats what I was looking for. Does that go in a separate private function though? And ajax doesn't get confused by a different function talking to it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a try/catch statement, like this :

```
public function mask_as_user() {
    $this->load->model('User_model', '', true);

    $email = $this->input->post('email');

    try {

        //there should be some front-end validation here too, but if not permitter, dont allow this to proceed.
        if (strpos($this->session->userdata('user_type'), 'permitter') === false) {
            throw new Exception('You are not an admin.');
        }

        //save the current admin account, so we know where to switch back to
        $admin_account_email = $this->session->userdata('user_email');

        //logout current user to not have overlapping session data
        //$this->logout(false, true);

        $user_data = $this->User_model->get_user_data($email);

        if ($user_data[0]){
            $user_data = $this->clean_user_data($user_data[0]);
        } else {
            throw new Exception('This is not an active client account.');
        }
        //get userdata for user-mask account and remove unneccessary data (such as login credentials) from session array

        //prevent switching into admin accounts. Not really any sensitive data that the rest of the company can't access elsewhere, but maybe someday there will be.
        if (strpos($user_data['user_type'], 'permitter') !== false) {
            throw new Exception('You cannot switch into an admin account.');
        }

        //foreach column loaded from database, create a session value.
        $this->session->set_userdata($user_data);

        //set user to loggedin.
        $this->session->set_userdata('loggedin', TRUE);

        //set the current admin account which the mask is being applied to. We will need this for returning back to the admin account without having to logout.
        $this->session->set_userdata('admin_account_email', $admin_account_email);

        $return['status'] = 'success';
        $return['redir_url'] = '/site_client/dashboard';

        header('Content-type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($return);
        return true;
    }

    catch (Exception $e) {
        $return['message']= $e->getMessage();
        $return['status'] = 'error';
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($return);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I like @user15 answer, here is another approach where you build you data then return it:

```
public function mask_as_user(){
    $this->load->model('User_model', '', true);
    $email = $this->input->post('email');
    $data = array();
    if(strpos($this->session->userdata('user_type'), 'permitter') === false){
        $data['success'] = false;
        $data['message']= 'You are not an admin.';
        return $data;
    }

    $admin_account_email = $this->session->userdata('user_email');
    $user_data = $this->User_model->get_user_data($email);

    if (!$user_data[0]){
        $data['success'] = false;
        $data['message']= 'This is not an active client account.';
        return $data;
    }
    $user_data = $this->clean_user_data($user_data[0]);

    if (strpos($user_data['user_type'], 'permitter') !== false) {
        $data['success'] = false;
        $data['message']= 'You cannot switch into an admin account.';
        return $data;
    }

    $this->session->set_userdata($user_data);

    //set user to loggedin.
    $this->session->set_userdata('loggedin', TRUE);

    //set the current admin account which the mask is being applied to. We will need this for returning back to the admin account without having to logout.
    $this->session->set_userdata('admin_account_email', $admin_account_email);

    $data['success'] = true;
    $data['redir_url'] = '/site_client/dashboard';

    return $data;
}
```

call it like this:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
$data = mask_as_user();
echo json_encode($data);
```

then when you parse the json check the status bool `$data['success']`

Comment: thanks for the help! I went with @user15's but this is great to have in the repertoire. Really appreciate it.